# How to return only nodes that matches all relationships in a Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Supposing I have the following relationships, how can I return all nodes connected to `3`, `4` and `5` (node `1`), but ignore nodes that have some of them, but not all (nodes `2` and `3`).

```
1--4
1--5
1--6

2--4

3--5
3--6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question has a typo, and you meant to ask how to return all nodes that are connected to all of these nodes: 4, 5, and 6.

Here is a query that is explicitly just for 4, 5, and 6.

```
MATCH (n)--({id: 4}), (n)--({id: 5}), (n)--({id: 6})
RETURN n;
```

And here is a query that could be used for any list of ids (in this example: 7, 8, 9, 10):

```
WITH [7, 8, 9, 10] AS list
MATCH (n)--(x)
WITH list, LENGTH(list) AS lth, n, COLLECT(DISTINCT x.id) AS cx
WHERE (LENGTH(cx) >= lth) AND ALL (i IN list WHERE i IN cx)
RETURN n;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. After some research, I was doing the same way you did in your first example. I will try the second example because in the first example I have to generate all the matches dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION clause : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-union.html#union-combine-two-queries-and-remove-duplicates

```
MATCH (n:Label)
WHERE (n)--(n4)
AND (n)--(n5)
AND (n)--(n6)
RETURN distinct(n)
MATCH (n)
WHERE (n)--(n4)
OR (n)--(n5)
RETURN distinct(n)
```